# Gedmo Translatable yaml mapping

Tags: symfony, doctrine-extensions

Is it possible to map Gedmo with yaml ? I'm using yaml file in my project and I would like to use Translatable from doctrine extensions but I have a problem with it.

I have something like that (one entity / one translation table) :

```html
class CategoryTranslation extends \Gedmo\Translatable\Entity\MappedSuperclass\AbstractTranslation
{
    /**
     * All required columns are mapped through inherited superclass
     */
}
```

but, when I run "doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql" command, I've got an error :

**There is no column with name 'locale' on table 'category_translation'.**

I have the feeling that yaml mapping "can't see" Gedmo AbstractTranslation class...

Do you have an idea of the problem ?
Thank you !

**EDIT :**

To avoid discussions in comments, I post an answer.

```html
MyProject\MyBundle\Entity\Category:
    type: entity
    table: category
    repositoryClass: MyProject\MyBundle\Repository\CategoryRepository
    gedmo:
        tree:
            type: nested
        translation:
            locale: locale
            entity: MyProject\MyBundle\Entity\Translation\CategoryTranslation
    fields:
        label:
            type: string
            length: 255
            gedmo:
                - translatable
```

With this config, I had to create a Translation.CategoryTranslation.orm.yml file because there is no database migration. And, there problem is really here :

```html
MyProject\MyBundle\Entity\Translation\CategoryTranslation:
  type: entity
  table: category_translation
  repositoryClass: Gedmo\Translatable\Entity\Repository\TranslationRepository
  indexes:
    category_translation_idx:
      columns: [ locale, object_class, field, foreign_key ]
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
  fields:
    locale:
      type: string
      length: 8
    object_class:
      type: string
      length: 255
    field:
      type: string
      length: 32
    foreign_key:
      type: string
      length: 64
    content:
      type: text
```

By doing this, the database migration works. I have a new table named category_translation. But, when I try to add a new translation, there is an error in my sql request generated by doctrine. Object_class field and foreign_key are null.

**Here, the SQL request generated by doctrine :**

INSERT INTO category_translation (locale, object_class, field, foreign_key, content) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [\"fr\", null, \"name\", null, \"toto\"]:\n\nSQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'object_class' cannot be null"}

Comment: https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/v2.4.x/doc/translatable.md#yaml-mapping-example
Have you tried this example?

Comment: Hi  svgrafov , thank you to help me.

I did the same thing but I don't know if I have to create a yaml file for CategoryTranslation. And, if I don't do that, there is no table category_translation when I want to migrate my database

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: Have you tried uncommenting this line
#     entity: Translatable\Fixture\CategoryTranslation 
?

Comment: I would like a translation table for each entity, so here what I have in my Category.orm.yml file : 

    gedmo:
        translation:
            locale: locale
            entity: MyProject\MyBundle\Entity\Translation\CategoryTranslation